# Why is my response always 0 after using parameters in OleDB?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oledb

I have a simple .aspx login website and I use OleDB for local validation.

Here is my problem: After finding SQL Injection vulnerability, I decided to use parameters. But after using parameters my response is always "0" (Same as "Authenticated=false"). But if I don't use parameters, my response is "1" (Same as "Authenticated=true").

Here some pics while debugging:

Without parameters where the response=1 (Authenticated):
[image: Without parameters]

With code:

```
string idstr = Request.QueryString["id"];
            idstr.Replace("''", "");
            string passpath = Request.QueryString["password"];
            passpath.Replace("''", "");

            OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\Users\hugow_000\Desktop\OSGS_Kantine_htm_design\Kantine_data.accdb; Persist Security Info = False;";
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            connect.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from User_data where Stamnummer="+idstr+" and Wachtwoord="+ passpath;

            OleDbDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int code = 0;
            while (read.Read())
            {
                code = code + 1;
            }
            if (code == 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/AuthKeyGEN.aspx?Auth=true&id=" + idstr + "&password=" + passpath + "");

            }
            if (code > 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?response=0");
            }
            if (code < 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?response=0");
            }
        }
```

And with parameters where the response is 0 (Not Authenticated):
[image: With parameters]

And with code:

```
string idstr = Request.QueryString["id"];
            idstr.Replace("''", "");
            string passpath = Request.QueryString["password"];
            passpath.Replace("''", "");

            OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\Users\hugow_000\Desktop\OSGS_Kantine_htm_design\Kantine_data.accdb; Persist Security Info = False;";
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            connect.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from User_data where Stamnummer=@idstr and Wachtwoord=@passpath";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@idstr", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = idstr;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@passpath", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = passpath;

            OleDbDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int code = 0;
            while (read.Read())
            {
                code = code + 1;
            }
            if (code == 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/AuthKeyGEN.aspx?Auth=true&id=" + idstr + "&password=" + passpath + "");

            }
            if (code > 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?response=0");
            }
            if (code < 1)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?response=0");
            }
        }
```

I am using the same credentials in both scenarios,
So why is my response always 0 if I use parameters in here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look anything wrong but try using `OleDbType.VarChar` instead of `OleDbType.BSTR` since both the parameter are of `string` type; like

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@idstr", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = idstr;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@passpath", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = passpath;
```

Also as a side note, instead of using `select *` use a `count()` query like below in which case you can use `ExecuteScalar()` rather than using `ExecuteReader()`

```
"select count(*) from User_data 
where Stamnummer=@idstr and Wachtwoord=@passpath";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ms Access uses ? as parameter place holders and the order is important (your order is correct). The parameter objects can be named as the name is ignored by the engine so it really does not matter but might make for more readable code. See [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) as reference.

```
cmd.CommandText = "select 1 from User_data where Stamnummer = ? and Wachtwoord= ?";
```

Also change the parameter types as @Rahul had pointed out to `VarChar`.

### General recommendations

1. Wrap your connection in a using block.This ensures your connection is always closed even when an Exception is encountered.
2. Like @Rahul said use `ExecuteScalar` instead of ExecuteReader. Use either COUNT(*) or hardcode 1 as the result: `select 1 from User_data ...`
3. Never ever store passwords as plain text, ever! This is horrible practice and makes for a very unsecure app. I have submitted a complete solution to creating a password hash that you could copy/paste and use directly.